# How to theme the registration form in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I'm using drupal 7 and I want to customize the registration form, and user login form.
I'm using this code in template.tpl.php:

```
function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  $hooks['user_login']=array(
    'render element'=>'form',
    'template' =>'templates/user-login',
  );
  $hooks['user_register']=array(
    'render element'=>'form',
    'template' =>'templates/user-register',
  );
  $hooks['user_pass']=array(
    'render element'=>'form',
    'template' =>'templates/user-pass',
  );
  return $hooks;
}
```

the strange thing is 'user_login' and 'user_pass' are work but 'user_register' not.
someone please let me know why and show me how to solve it.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

That's the wrong way to override themes in Drupal, what you're doing there is replacing the original items provided by Drupal core in the theme registry. Doing this you'll get unpredictable results, which would explain why a couple of them work and one doesn't.

The best way to override the theme is by using the function naming convention provided by Drupal, `MYTHEME_theme_name(&$vars)`. So in your case the three functions would look like this

```
function MYTHEME_user_login(&$vars) {

}

function MYTHEME_user_register(&$vars) {

}

function MYTHEME_user_pass(&$vars) {

}
```

If you do want to change the existing themes' template files then you should use [`hook_theme_registry_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7):

```
function MYTHEME_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $theme_registry['user_login'] = array(
    'render element'=>'form',
    'template' =>'templates/user-login'
  );
}
```

Make sure you clear Drupal's caches any time you add or change a hook or the changes won't be reflected in your site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
About MyTHEME_theme_name(&$vars), actually I don't know it. could you send to me a link about it?
about hook_theme_registry_alter, I do exactly what you tell me. but it still doesn't work.